# System Sound Level in UWP

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I have searched through documentations, but cannot find a way to figure out either the system volume or the volume level at which the app would play

Read through:

[Sound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/sound?redirectedfrom=MSDN&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[ElementSound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.elementsoundplayer?view=winrt-18362)

Is there a way to find it in UWP?

Comment: Could you explain why you want to figure out this?

Comment: I have making a viewability SDK for UWP apps and I need to report volume changes to viewability partners (like MOAT, IAS). Viewability SDK is for finding viewability of ads being shown in UWP apps.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to report volume changes to viewability

Thanks for your interest. Unfortunately, currently there is no better way to report the volume you said. We can only control the app level's volume such as mediaplayperelement volume setting. We do not have any event to listen for system volume changes. We suggest you could make [desktop bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) app and use desktop extension part to get system volume and send it to UWP client with [**AppService**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service).